# Prototype machine whose complete design is based on the relational model

Tags: hardware, relational-model

In the Preface to Ted Codd's *[The Relational Model for Database Management, Version 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201141922)*, he writes (first paragraph):

> Today, if you have a well-designed
>   database management system, you have
>   the keys to the kingdom of data
>   processing and decision support. 
>   **That is why there now exists a prototype machine whose complete
>   design is based on the relational
>   model. Its arithmetic hardware is
>   quite minor part of the
>   architecture.** In fact, the old term
>   "computer system" now seems like a
>   misnomer.

Does anyone know what prototype machine Ted Codd was referring to?  I would love to read old Computer Science / Computer Engineering papers describing this machine.